# Detect Whether Numeric Keyboard Has Return Key or Not

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, uitextfield

On iOS, the numeric keyboard has a return key on iPad but not on iPhone.

I am taking the standard approach of adding a toolbar as `inputAccessoryView` of the target text field, with a "Done" button in it.

However, on iPad the keyboard already has a return key (labelled "Done", "Next", etc. according to one of the constants enumerated in `UIReturnKeyType`); I would like to display the accessory view only when necessary.

**Is there a way to detect the presence of such key, other than the (inelegant) method of querying the user interface idiom**?

---

I ask this because, the fact that the iPad keyboard has a return key and the iPhone one does not seems like an implementation detail, in principle unrelated to whether the device is a phone or a tablet. As such, it feels like it might change in the future, breaking my (unrobust) solution.